# How to cast an Int32Array to a Uint8Array without copying

Tags: node.js

I have an object of type `Int32Array` of length `1` and I would like to cast it to an object of type `Uint8Array` of length `4`, preferably without copying the memory content. How can I do this?

**[UPDATE]**

To explain my problem better, consider the following code:

```
const view = new DataView(int32array.buffer);
const uni8array = new Uint8Array(int32array.length * 4);
for (let i=0; i<int32array.length; i++) {
    uni8array[i*4+0] = view.getUint8(i*4+0);
    uni8array[i*4+1] = view.getUint8(i*4+1);
    uni8array[i*4+2] = view.getUint8(i*4+2);
    uni8array[i*4+3] = view.getUint8(i*4+3);
}
```

This code does exactly what I want to do but it copies the original array into a new one. I was hoping there's a way to do the same without copying the memory.

Comment: Perhaps make a [DataView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView) that provides a different interface (including the ability to pull any uint8 value) on  your ArrayBuffer object.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks. I've already looked into that. It's just that `DataView` only provides me with the ability to read the data one element at a time. I was hoping to find a way to cast the whole array without copying.

Comment: What are you really trying to do then?  Please describe the whole problem.  Why you start with a Int32Array in the first place and why you want the same data in a Uint8Array without copying.  Right now, your question is an XY problem where you are asking for a particular solution without describing the real problem here and thus we can't see the whole problem and can't offer you things you haven't even thought of.

Comment: @jfriend00 I updated the question. The problem that I'm trying to solve is that I have two libraries. One outputs `Int32Array` and the other expects `Uint8Array`. The data is the same, only their type is the problem.

Comment: So, converting an Int32Array to a Uint8Array invites a whole bunch of questions, particularly related to platform byte order.

Comment: I understand the byte order problem but at least in my case, it's irrelevant. The array in my case is an image and the problem is that the first library outputs each pixel as an Int32 which is dumb.

Comment: I don't see any way to do what you're trying to do from plain Javascript.  If this is a Javascript coded module that creates the Uint32Array, maybe you could edit the source module to create and populate a Uint8Array in the first place.

Comment: Thanks, I needed to make sure that I'm not missing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any way to do what you're trying to do from plain Javascript.

If the source module is a Javascript coded module that creates the `Uint32Array`, maybe you could edit the source module to create and populate a `Uint8Array` in the first place and avoid the conversion problem.

---

Another possibility is that you could make your own wrapper for the `Uint32Array` that gives you access like a virtual `Uint8Array` where you hide the messiness of dynamically getting the appropriate Uint8 value out of the Uint32Array (without having to copy it) and then just code access to it using your wrapper methods.

Comment: @mehran - I added a note about how you could make a wrapper around the Uint32Array that gives you a Uint8Array-like interface.

Answer (score 1):

(better late than never?)

Construct the Uint8Array directly from the ArrayBuffer returned from `.buffer`. Or if using Node.js, then `Buffer.from(...)`. Search for "shares the same allocated memory" at https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffers-and-typedarrays.

```
const u32s = Uint32Array.of (3, 8);
const u8s_plainJS = new Uint8Array(u32s.buffer);
//const u8s_NodeJS = Buffer.from(u32s.buffer);
console.log(u8s_plainJS);  // [ 3, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0 ] on my little-endian platform
```

As others have mentioned, if you need to be concerned about endian-ness, you may need to use DataView.